# 500 Internal Server Error when access the phpmyadmin using with command in Bitnami Apache

Tags: php, wordpress

I get the error like "Internal Server Error" when I access http://localhost:8888/phpmyadmin/ url for open the database in bitnami apache. I have try to resolve the issue using command still do get the solution.

[image: Internal Server Error]

So, Please help me for same.

Comment: try port 80 or 443

Comment: Did u explicitly install PHP on port 8888?

Comment: Check your folder permissions. Post your apache error log here.

Comment: @Penguine, I have installed the wordpress on bitnami server. First time, its worked as command If I have given but second day I try to access the phpmyadmin as per same command. so, now it's not working. so, what's the reason???

Comment: Did u create SSH tunnel?

Comment: @PriyankaModi please check this link: https://community.bitnami.com/t/internal-server-error-500/48324/5

Comment: @Penguine, I didn't get the information about my issue in this link. I don't know about SSH tunnel because only share my phpmyadmin details only

Comment: @PriyankaModi then please post the error logs here, because without that it will be like needle in a haystack

Comment: @Penguine - I got the solution. Thanks for reply me ... :)

Comment: Ur welcm
:-)
Please post ur solution here, to enable others to rectify the same problem, if any, in future